# Unique FormControl Names

Tags: angular

I upgraded my Angular project from 7 to 9. The upgrade has broken my custom directive because it appears that the lifecycle of objects is different.

My original problem is that I need to be to access form controls uniquely based on the data that is loaded. For example, the user loads 11 records and changes the name on record 8. I need to be able to access the form control for the 8th record.

I found a solution from a tutorial a while back. (I don't have the link anymore.) It uses a custom directive to add the form controls when the data is changed. The form control names have a unique name, such as "record8" for the 8th record. (My actual numbers aren't sequential.) It accesses formGroupDirective.form to get the FormGroup that contains the controls. In the newer Angular versions, the form property is null at this point.

I either need to fix my code or find a completely new solution to accomplish the same thing.

Here is a general look at my current solution:

my.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit{
  // Build an empty array for the form controls
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    records: this.formBuilder.group([])
  });
}
```

my.component.html

```html
<form [connectMyForm]="myRecords$ | async" ...>
  ...
</form>
```

myconnect.directive.ts

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[connectMyForm]'
})

export class MyConnectDirective {
    constructor(private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective) { }

    @Input('connectMyForm')
    set data(values: any) {
        // Add uniquely named form controls based on the data that is passed in.
        // PROBLEM: this.formGroupDirective.form is now null at this point.
        let recordGroup = this.formGroupDirective.form.get('records') as FormGroup; //FAIL form is null
        recordGroup.controls = {}; //Remove anything existing.

        for (let value of values) {
            // Add form control with unique name.
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular 9 you can make sure that your component binding is executed after `FormGroupDirective` binding by placing `[formGroup]` before your directive binding:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" [connectMyForm]="myRecords$ | async">
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       goes first
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/RGDRYWFsnHUEldxl6LU1)**

Comment: This worked. Funny enough, this was one of the first things I thought of. But then I though, nah, the order wouldn't suddenly matter. I would have saved myself a lot of time if I had just tried it. Also, I am using IntelliJ. If I use the code formatter (CTRL-ALT-L), it will automatically change the order. I will have to report this to them as a bug since now it breaks my code.